# Iterate through all Objects of a certain type and execute a method

Tags: c#

I am fairly new but I have learnt a lot of the basics so there may be a topic I need to learn that solves this problem so I am looking for advice.

I have a class I have written and I have my Main() method where I am creating 8 instances of that class.

```
namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class ExampleClass
    {
        private bool status;

        public ExampleClass()
        {

        }

        public bool getStatus()
        {
            return status;
        }
        public void methodA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Run Method A");
        }

        public void methodB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Run Method B");
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExampleClass obj1 = new ExampleClass();
            ExampleClass obj2 = new ExampleClass();
            ExampleClass obj3 = new ExampleClass();
            ExampleClass obj4 = new ExampleClass();
            ExampleClass obj5 = new ExampleClass();



            if (obj1.getStatus()==true)
            {
                obj1.methodA();
            }
            else
            {
                obj1.methodB();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a call to a class that will check a status of each of these objects and it will execute one of two methods.

**So what I am asking is there anyway to loop through each object and access its fields and methods?**

You can see I have the condition statement at the bottom but I don't want to do one for each object, I want to cycle through a group of them objects but can't seem to figure it out.

P.S I apologise for not posting code, I was just looking for a bit of advice. I didn't think people would jump all over that. I have written out a simple idea of what I am trying to do.

Thank you

Comment: *Loop*s and *iterations* act on a collection or array.  Create one and put your objects in it.

Comment: The rules for submitting questions to Stack Overflow would deem this question off topic.  You need to make an attempt at solving the problem yourself.  If it doesn't work then you can post the attempt you made, a description of the issue with the code and what you're trying to acheive.  Read [mcve]

Comment: @meJustAndrew In fairness, learning the basics doesn't imply one has mastered them, or that they have learned *all* of them.  I don't think their question is inconsistent with their claimed level of experience.

Comment: It really would help if you explained what you mean by “access its fields and methods”. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Christopher has answered my question and it maybe basic but I am new, basics to one person might not be the same to another. Why give negative feedback? Christopher helped me out and put me in the right direction. Why can't people just be positive. Anyway I have updated the question with example code to help anyone else who need a bit of advice.

Comment: @Richard What negative feedback are you referring to?

Comment: Not you Amy, the first guy who was ranting on about I don't know the basics. Your feedback was positive, i haven't yet mastered the topics yet and was just looking for a bit of direction as I am self learning. <It seems his comment has disappeared or at least I don't see it.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work with a bunch of parameters. C# is not the kind of language where you can form Variable names at runtime from Strings. (Well, at least not without something *very* advanced like reflection. Wich you really should not be using for that either way.)

A Collection is the droid you are looking for. For this case, I would pick an array.

Wichever type of Collection you pick, you then need a loop to itterate over it. for and foreach are most common here.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I knew there was a way like this but couldn't find the keyword and Collections is that word. Thank you for your positive feedback it has helped a newbie concentrate on coding and not the politics of posting on a forum. Cheers.